# How to combine 3 selectors with a:hover tag?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS rules:

```css
#toolbar1 a:hover { 
    color: #415682;
}

#toolbar2 a:hover { 
    color: #415682;
}

#toolbar3 a:hover { 
    color: #415682;
}
```

How can I combine these into a single rule?  I've tried

```css
#toolbar1 #toolbar2 #toolbar3 a:hover { 
    color: #415682;
}
```

but it didn't work.  I've tried placing commas between these, also, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For wide browser compatibility, you’ll just have to repeat yourself:

```css
#toolbar1 a:hover,
#toolbar2 a:hover,
#toolbar3 a:hover {
    color: #415682;
}
```

[Some day](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-matches-pseudo), `:matches` might be usable:

```css
:matches(#toolbar1, #toolbar2, #toolbar3) a:hover {
    color: #415682;
}
```

If you want something similar before then, CSS preprocessors are an option.

In this particular case, though, the structure suggests a class might be appropriate:

```css
.toolbar a:hover {
    color: #415682;
}
```